# Listings line numbers and figure

Tags: listings, line-numbering

I'm using `listings` to typeset some C inside a `figure` environment next to a diagram, and I have the numbers on the left. My problem is in `two-column` mode the line numbers appear in what should be the margin, outside the text area (i.e., numbers are not justified with the left-hand side of the column, but instead slightly to the left of the justification). The code I'm using is:

```
\begin{figure*}
  \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
   \begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
    i = 0;
    j = 1;
   \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
     \includegraphics{figure}
  \end{minipage}
 \caption{My caption}
 \label{fig:blah}
\end{figure*}
```

Is there a way to keep the line numbers from `lstlisting` inside the text area?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) code to write the line numbers is stored in `\lst@PlaceNumber`. Under `numbers=left` it is defined as:

```
\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont
  \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}}%
```

which prints the number as a `l`eft over`lap`, causing the "problems" you experience. You could just push the entire `lstlisting` over by *at least* the above amount (say, `1em+\lst@numbersep`) to allow the left overlap to still be within the text block boundary:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \makeatletter%
  \hspace*{\dimexpr 1em+\lst@numbersep}%
  \makeatother%
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
i = 0;
j = 1;
\end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
     \includegraphics{figure}
  \end{minipage}
 \caption{My caption}
 \label{fig:blah}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

I've added [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) to highlight the text block boundary, and the `[demo]` option to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) in order to run the MWE. They are not needed in your final document.

Alternatively you can set the numbers to be shown left *globally* (using `\lstset{numbers=left}`) and then redefine `\lst@PlaceNumber` accordingly:

```
\makeatletter%
\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\makebox[\dimexpr 1em+\lst@numbersep][l]{\normalfont
  \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}}%
\makeatother%
```

The global setting is required in order to have the redefinition last beyond `\begin{lstlisting}`.

Answer (score 5):

I guess a simple solution could be to use the `xleftmargin=...` setting in the listings environment. Take a look at the listings documentation.